# Clone or duplicate object from array then push and rename using es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want have listing component where it has action to edit, duplicate or delete.
I already selecting the id to be clone but it's not pushing next to the item.
I'm using es6

Here's my code

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  formList: []
})

const handleDuplicateItem = id => {
  const duplicateSource = [...state.formList];
  const duplicateItem = duplicateSource.find(item => item.id !== id);
  duplicateSource.push(duplicateItem);

  setState({
    ...state,
    formList: [duplicateSource],
  });
};

<FormItemList
  dataSource={state.formList}
/>
```

Comment: What do you mean *"not pushing next to the item"*? If you mean the duplicate is always at the end of the array, that's what push *does*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for example, [1,1,2,3] 1 is the clone item.

Comment: So why push? That always adds to the end. Look at e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

You want the copy next to the item that you copy(note that you now have duplicate id's and you can't map the data to jsx without warning anymore).

You can use reduce to do this:

```
const handleDuplicateItem = id => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    formList: state.formList.reduce((result, item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        //push an extra shallow copy of the item to result
        result.push({ ...item });
      }
      result.push(item);
      return result;
    }, []),
  });
};
```